# ValueError: could not convert string to float?

Tags: python, string, valueerror

I am a beginner in terms of coding. Python gives me the same error whenever I try to do calculation. I use python 3.9. I do not make typo when I enter input (this one was 5.2). Could you please help me?

```
"""
length of rectangle = a
width of rectangle = b
calculate the area and perimeter of the rectangle
"""

a = 6
b = float(input("width: "))

area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " + str(area) + " perimeter: " + str(perimeter))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP\OneDrive - Karabuk University\Belgeler\Downloads\first.py", line 8, in <module>
    b = float(input("width: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.2&
```

Comment: how can `'5.2&'` be converted to a float?

Comment: what I enter is just 5.2 I don't know how it becomes '5.2&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with the code, not the code, whether your input key has some hidden characters attached

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[/]
└─$vim demo.py
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[/]
└─$python3 demo.py
width: 5.2
area: 31.200000000000003 perimeter: 22.4
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[/]
└─$cat demo.py
"""
length of rectangle = a
width of rectangle = b
calculate the area and perimeter of the rectangle
"""

a = 6
b = float(input("width: "))

area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " + str(area) + " perimeter: " + str(perimeter))
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[/]
└─$
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you exactly defined my problem. I will be looking for the solution of hidden character. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. I guess the problem is your input: '5.2&'. You made a typo here. Revove '&' and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I enter 5.2 and have no idea why it becomes '5.2&

Answer (score -1):

```
"""
length of rectangle = a
width of rectangle = b
calculate the area and perimeter of the rectangle
"""

a = 6
b = float(input("width: "))

area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " , area , " perimeter: " , perimeter)
```